# Copiar y pegar en la última fila disponible VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Qué tal, estoy copiando los datos de archivos .xls al libro en el cuál ejecuto la macro, el código lo probé en un libro llamado "Test" para hacer la prueba del copiado y pegado que realiza con éxito, el problema que tengo es cómo identificar la última fila disponible para poder pegar los nuevos datos debajo de la última fila, a su vez me gustaría hacerlo en un loop, probé una macro que realicé pero solamente me pega un valor en la última celda de la columna A.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DailyTrans_MDM()
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom  As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Open file with data to be copied
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Daily Reports (*.xl*)," & "*.xl*", 1, "Select Report ", "Open File", False)
'If cancel then EXIT
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
Exit Sub
Else
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)
End If

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Copy Range from the workbook i want
wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:M65536").Copy

'Find the last row so i can paste the new info there
Dim last As Long

last = wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

wsCopyTo.Range("A" & last).Copy Destination:=wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Paste into the last row of the ACTUALWORKBOOK
'wsCopyTo.Range().PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,
'Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Close file that was opened
wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Intento :

```
a = wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsCopyTo.Range("A" & a).Copy_ 
Destination:=Template.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

La última fila la puedes obtener así:

```
Dim uf as Long
Dim sht as worksheet

Set sht = Workbooks.Sheets("MiHoja")
uf = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

No entiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer en loop.
Para pegar los datos en la última fila copia tu rango y los pegas en la primera celda vacía de la última fila con datos. A esa última fila le sumas uno para que no machaque la última fila con datos que tengas:

```
MiRango.Copy HojaDestino.Range("A" & uf + 1)
```

Previamente tendrás que tener definido MiRango, claro.

Guiándome un poco con tus datos tendrías que hacer esto:

```
wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:M65536").Copy Template.Range("A" & uf + 1)
```

Con eso debería funcionar el pegado de un rango.

Saludos.

Comment: También puedes asignar la fila extra a `uf` así: `uf = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: @dogwall Gracias por la ayuda, en un momento lo pruebo, el loop es para que abra todos los archivos .xls dentro de la carpeta, a su vez va a copiar los datos de esos libros y pegarlos en el libro en el que corre la macro, por lo la lastrow va a cambiar siempre.